# Pythonic way to choose most recent value from a time-series DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time-series

I have a time-series that contains multiple values at each datetime.  Each datetime index has an associated datetime where the value was loaded, or 'loadtime', like so:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# time-series index
t = pd.date_range('09/01/2017', '09/02/2017', freq='1H')
t = t.repeat(3)
n = len(t)

# data values
y = np.full((n), 0.0)
y = y.reshape(n//3, 3)
y[:, 1] = 1.0
y[:, 2] = 2.0
y = y.flatten()

# load timestamp
random_range = np.arange(0, 60)
base_date = np.datetime64('2017-10-01 12:00')
loadtimes = [base_date + np.random.choice(random_range) for x in range(n)]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=t, data={'y': y, 'loadtime': loadtimes})


>>> df.head(12)
                    loadtime            y
2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 01:59:00 0.0
2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 09:23:00 1.0
2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 03:35:00 2.0
2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-01 17:26:00 0.0
2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-01 16:44:00 1.0
2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-02 12:50:00 2.0
2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-02 11:30:00 0.0
2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-02 11:17:00 1.0
2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-01 20:23:00 2.0
2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-02 15:27:00 0.0
2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-02 18:08:00 1.0
2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-01 16:06:00 2.0
```

So far, I have come up with this solution to iterate over all unique values...but this could be expensive as the time-series increasing in length (and multiple values). It looks like a bit of a hack and not so clean:

```
new_index = df.index.unique()
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=new_index, columns=['y'])

# cycle through unique indices to find max loadtime
dfg = df.groupby(df.index)
for i, dfg_i in dfg:
    max_index = dfg_i['loadtime'] == dfg_i['loadtime'].max()

    if i in df_new.index:
        df_new.loc[i, 'y'] = dfg_i.loc[max_index, 'y'].values[0]  # WHY IS THIS A LIST?

>>> df_new.head()
                    y
2017-09-01 00:00:00 1
2017-09-01 01:00:00 2
2017-09-01 02:00:00 0
2017-09-01 03:00:00 1
2017-09-01 04:00:00 1
```

How can I take a time-series with the latest 'loadtime' for each unique index?  Is there a more pythonic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create column from `DatetimeIndex` and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `y` column. Then use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) what return index (here `y` column values) by max values in `loadtime` per groups:

```
print (df.rename_axis('dat')
         .reset_index()
         .set_index('y')
         .groupby('dat')['loadtime']
         .idxmax()
         .to_frame('y'))

                       y
dat                     
2017-09-01 00:00:00  1.0
2017-09-01 01:00:00  2.0
2017-09-01 02:00:00  0.0
2017-09-01 03:00:00  1.0
```

Detail:

```
print (df.rename_axis('dat')
         .reset_index()
         .set_index('y'))

                    dat            loadtime
y                                          
0.0 2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 01:59:00
1.0 2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 09:23:00
2.0 2017-09-01 00:00:00 2017-10-02 03:35:00
0.0 2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-01 17:26:00
1.0 2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-01 16:44:00
2.0 2017-09-01 01:00:00 2017-10-02 12:50:00
0.0 2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-02 11:30:00
1.0 2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-02 11:17:00
2.0 2017-09-01 02:00:00 2017-10-01 20:23:00
0.0 2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-02 15:27:00
1.0 2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-02 18:08:00
2.0 2017-09-01 03:00:00 2017-10-01 16:06:00
```

**Timings**:

```
t = pd.date_range('01/01/2017', '12/25/2017', freq='1H')
#len(df)
#[25779 rows x 2 columns]

In [225]: %timeit (df.rename_axis('dat').reset_index().set_index('y').groupby('dat')['loadtime'].idxmax().to_frame('y'))
1 loop, best of 3: 870 ms per loop

In [226]: %timeit df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('y').idxmax()).rename(columns={'loadtime':'y'})
1 loop, best of 3: 4.96 s per loop
```

Comment: I think I took much time, it is a very tricky question. You answered it 18 min ago? Awesome

Comment: I test it and your solution is slow :(

Comment: Sir yeah cant disagree with that, no worries your method is awesome. you made use of reset index very well.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of groupby `level 0` and apply i.e

```
ndf = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x : x.set_index('y').idxmax()).rename(columns={'loadtime':'y'})
```

Ouptut : `ndf.head()`

```
                      y
2017-09-01 00:00:00  1.0
2017-09-01 01:00:00  1.0
2017-09-01 02:00:00  2.0
2017-09-01 03:00:00  1.0
2017-09-01 04:00:00  1.0
```